# Why does a band of paper I hold between my hands never breaks in the middle?

Tags: pressure

If I hold a band of paper with my digits and thumbs and start to pull, the band never breaks in the middle, but on one of the sides where I've put my fingers.  Why is this? Has it to do with the pressure I exert on the band with my thumbs and digits?

Comment: It breaks first where the stress in the paper is greatest (actually, the shear stress). The stress at the points where you are gripping it is larger than in the center, because in the center the tension is spread over the entire width of the paper. By the way, when you pull it that way, the shear stress will be maximum on a 45 degree line, so the tear should be jagged.

Comment: You probably meant a strip of connstant width, because a strip that is narrow in the middle and wide near your fingers will definitely tear in the narrow part.

Comment: Yes, I mean a strip (I accidentally used band, wich is the Dutch word for strip) of constant width.